# SQL SUM() across a subquery

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a **Ledger** table with this schema:

```
LedgerId    (int,not null)
Timestamp   (datetime, not null)
CostCenter  (int, not null)
Payee       (varchar(50), not null)
Type        (varchar(3),not null)
Category    (varchar(24), not null)
Amount      (decimal(8,2) not null)
Tag         (varchar(30),null)
Memo        (varchar(150), null)
```

where I record expense transactions for a small business.

At year's end I have to issue a form 1099 to the IRS for any contractor who received more than $600. I run the following query (thanks to StackExchange!) to get this:

```
SELECT Payee as Name, SUM(Amount)as Total FROM Ledger 
where (convert(date,timestamp) < convert(date,'2019-01-01')) 
and (convert(date,timestamp) > convert(date,'2017-12-31')) 
and category like '%Contract%' 
group by Payee having SUM(amount) > 600 
order by Payee
```

This is great, and gives me a list of each contractor and the total amount for 2018.

What I would like now is a query that will give me the total amount I have spent for these contractors in 2018 (also for IRS, form 1096). 
If I use this query as a subquery to obtain this total amount I get errors. How do I go about totaling all this contractor expense?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you saying this doesn't work?

```
select sum(total)
from (select Payee as Name, SUM(Amount) as Total 
      from Ledger 
      where timestamp < '2019-01-01' and
            timestamp >= '2018-01-01' and
            category like '%Contract%' 
      group by Payee
      having sum(amount) > 600 
     ) l;
```

You shouldn't need date conversions for the logic you want to implement.

Comment: Your version works perfectly.  I tried exacty that, except for the trailing **l;**, and got syntax errors. I admit I have no idea what this is.  And after a bit of googling, I see where this is an alias, and it clearly allows the query to work. I will have to research a little more to understand how this works.  Thanks!

Comment: @user3235770 . . . MySQL requires that all derived tables (subqueries in the `from` clause) have a table alias.